# Change Label Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I change a label's text? This is what I have tried.

```
labelCheckBox.text = @"This is the new label";
```

I connected the label in Interface builder for labelCheckBox and created an outlet for it. In the Didload the label's text changed, but in another method inside the class it does not have the new value.

```
-(void)settext:(NSString*)newLabelText{

labelCheckBox.text = newLabelText;
 //    labelCheckBox = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//    labelCheckBox.text = @"This is the new label";

}
```

I am calling the method in another class as shown here:

```
    [New settext:@"All Transaction"];
```

The value of '`NewLabelText`' after printing it in NSLog is: " `All Transaction` ". But when I assign ' `LabelCheckBox.Text = NewLabelText` ', I print the value of '`LabelCheckBox.Text`',
and it gives empty.

Comment: That code is correct so if you don't provide more information no one will be able to help you!

Comment: Are you creating this `UILabel` programatically or from Interface Builder?

Comment: Did you connect your label in Interface builder for labelCheckBox and create an outlet for it?

Comment: Please add information to your question so that people can understand your situation.  Try describing where the code is located, how your label is defined and connected, etc.  Tell us what you've already done to debug the problem.

Comment: Is the other method being called?  If so, what's the value of labelCheckBox in the other method?  (Use the debugger or NSLog() statements.)

Comment: Can you add more info? Are you trying to change the text upon an action? Are you trying to change the font? Please edit your OP with more info.

Comment: yes, the label content such as : text, font, color , doesn't change in any method in the class except 'DidLoad'!!!

Answer (score 4):

First of all if you use IB you need to create outlet and connection for your UILabel. The easiest way it's dragging from your label (control + drag) to your .h file of controller class. Then synthesize it in .m file and now you can change label text as you do this in question.

Answer (score 1):

the 'View' should load before setting the label text.

Answer (score 0):

iOS development sometimes gives you the silence treatment like Javascript to help prevent your app from crashing.  With that said, if you have created the `UILabel` in Interface Builder and have set an `IBOutlet` for it, make sure you change the text only after the `UILabel` is created.  (i.e. after `-viewDidLoad`).  You can set a break point to where you set the text change and a breakpoint at `-viewDidLoad` in the `UIViewController` that contains the `UILabel` to confirm the order of calls that's taking place.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code will change text in label with tag value**

In `scrollview` use this type to change the text in label

```
for(UIView *views in ScrollViewMain.subviews)
{
    UILabel *label = [views viewWithTag:[sender tag]+1000];
    label.text=str1;
}
```

It will really work.
thank you